An optimisation problem
Let $E\subset \mathbb R^2$ be compact, convex and connected. For $p_1,\ldots, p_n>0$ with
$$\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=1,$$
and a probability measure $\nu$ supported on $E$ of density $f$, we consider
$$\max_{X\in E^n :~ \mu_X\preceq \nu}~~ \left(\int_E |x|^2 \mu_X(dx)\equiv \sum_{i=1}^n p_i|x_i|^2\right),\quad\quad (\ast)$$
where $\preceq$ denotes the convex order, and for each $X=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)\in E^n$
$$\mu_X(dx):=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\delta_{x_i}(dx).$$
It is shown that $(\ast)$ admits a maximiser. Can we find a formula, a characterisation or a numerical scheme for the maximiser?
It is straightforward to verify $\Omega:=\{X\in E^n : \mu_X\preceq \nu\}$ is convex and the objective function to maximise is also convex. Therefore, the maximiser must be lying on the set of extremal points of $\Omega$. Intuitively, we need to pick $X\in \Omega$ such that $|x_i|$ is as large as possible. On the other hand, we may believe that
$$\Omega\cap \partial E^n=\emptyset. \quad (\mbox{How to prove it?})$$
For each $\epsilon>0$, define
$$E^n_\epsilon:=\{X\in E^n: d(X,\partial E^n):= \inf_{Y\in \partial E^n}|X-Y| \ge \epsilon\}.$$
Can we find/estimate some $\epsilon^*$ such that $\Omega\subset E^n_{\epsilon^*}$? If so, does this help to guess the $X\in \Omega$ "as large as possible"?
PS : We say that two probability measures $\mu,\nu$ satisfy  $\mu\preceq \nu$ if for any convex function $h:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ it holds
$$\int h d\mu \le \int h d\nu.$$

Hi Iosif. $n$ is fixed (in general $n\le 10$). The definition of "increasing convex order" is added

@IosifPinelis My bad. I mean they are increasing in convex order. Corrected

for sure the p-barycenter $y=\sum p_i x_i$ of the maximizer $X$ must match the barycenter $y_\nu=\int x\nu(dx)$ of $\nu$.

@leomonsaingeon Absolutely. $\mu_X \preceq \nu$ implies that $\mu_X, \nu$ have the same barycentre

oh yes, of course, convex ordering iself already gives that, how silly of me... Isn't there a dual problem that would be worth looking into?

Why would we believe that $\Omega\cap E^n=\emptyset$, even intuitively? I don't see it

I mean $\Omega \cap \partial E^n=\emptyset$. Intuitively if part of the support of $\mu_X$  is located on the boundary, $\mu_X\preceq \nu$ may not hold (my intuition)

of course, I made a typo and forgot a $\partial$. But I'm asking precisely "why is this your intuition"?

@leomonsaingeon My feeling is as follows: $\mu_X\preceq \nu$ is equivalent to say there exists a martingale $(M,N)$ such that $M\sim \mu_X$, $N\sim\nu$. So, $\mathbb E[N | M=x_i]=x_i$. As $N$ admits a density, $N$ is lying in the interior of $E^n$ almost surely, and so it is $\mathbb E[N | M=x_i]$, while $x_i$ is lying at the boundary. Contradiction!
